# Cannot use dpdk_cryptodev for creating a virtual bdev in spdk

Tags: dpdk

I configured and built SPDK using --with-crypto option and I want to create a crypto virtual bdev over an existing bdev, but seems like dpdk_cryptodev is not supporting the encrypt/decrypt operations.

For setting up dpdk_cryptodev for creating crypto bdev:

```
./rpc.py -s /var/tmp/nvmf_tgt.sock dpdk_cryptodev_scan_accel_module
./rpc.py -s /var/tmp/nvmf_tgt.sock dpdk_cryptodev_set_driver -d crypto_qat
./rpc.py -s /var/tmp/nvmf_tgt.sock accel_assign_opc -o encrypt -m dpdk_cryptodev
./rpc.py -s /var/tmp/nvmf_tgt.sock accel_assign_opc -o decrypt -m dpdk_cryptodev
./rpc.py -s /var/tmp/nvmf_tgt.sock framework_start_init
```

On using the accel_get_module_info rpc command:

```
[
  {
    "module": "software",
    "supported ops": [
      "copy",
      "fill",
      "dualcast",
      "compare",
      "crc32c",
      "copy_crc32c",
      "compress",
      "decompress",
      "encrypt",
      "decrypt",
      "xor"
    ]
  },
  {
    "module": "dpdk_cryptodev",
    "supported ops": [
      "copy",
      "fill"
    ]
  }
]
```

Here, I dont see encrypt and decrypt in supported ops for dpdk_cryptodev. Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> Here, I dont see encrypt and decrypt in supported ops for dpdk_cryptodev. Any idea on how to fix it?

As I know `crypto_qat` is not currently supported for encryption or decryption operations.

I consider you can use a different driver such as `crypto_aesni`.

Set up set this driver this way:

```
./rpc.py -s /var/tmp/nvmf_tgt.sock dpdk_cryptodev_scan_accel_module
./rpc.py -s /var/tmp/nvmf_tgt.sock dpdk_cryptodev_set_driver -d crypto_aesni
./rpc.py -s /var/tmp/nvmf_tgt.sock accel_assign_opc -o encrypt -m dpdk_cryptodev
./rpc.py -s /var/tmp/nvmf_tgt.sock accel_assign_opc -o decrypt -m dpdk_cryptodev
./rpc.py -s /var/tmp/nvmf_tgt.sock framework_start_init
```

Comment: Got this error:
accel_dpdk_cryptodev.c: 214:accel_dpdk_cryptodev_set_driver: *ERROR*: Unsupported driver crypto_aesni

Comment: If I use crypto_aesni_mb, I get the same issue as original

Comment: @VATSALTIWARI The error message indicates that the crypto_aesni driver is not supported on your platform.

Comment: @VATSALTIWARI you can use a different crypto driver, such as the crypto_software driver.